using nix-flakes on MBP, cannot import scipy
The idea of Nix is great and this is the third time in the past 10 years I tried to use Nix, hopefully, this time this strange issue could be solved!
I just started using Nix-flakes following this tutorial on my macbook
mkdir nix-python-dev && cd nix-python-dev
nix flake init --template "github:DeterminateSystems/zero-to-nix#python-dev"

then I edited the flake.nix file following this template, and here is my flake.nix file
description = "Example Python development environment for Zero to Nix";

  # Flake inputs
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "https://flakehub.com/f/NixOS/nixpkgs/0.2305.491812.tar.gz";
  };

  # Flake outputs
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs }:
    let
      # Systems supported
      allSystems = [
        "x86_64-linux" # 64-bit Intel/AMD Linux
        "aarch64-linux" # 64-bit ARM Linux
        "x86_64-darwin" # 64-bit Intel macOS
        "aarch64-darwin" # 64-bit ARM macOS
      ];

      # Helper to provide system-specific attributes
      forAllSystems = f: nixpkgs.lib.genAttrs allSystems (system: f {
        pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
      });
    in
    {
      # Development environment output
      devShells = forAllSystems ({ pkgs }: {
        default =
          let
            # Use Python 3.11
            python = pkgs.python311;
          in
          pkgs.mkShell {
            # The Nix packages provided in the environment
            packages = [
              # Python plus helper tools
              (python.withPackages (ps: with ps; [
                virtualenv # Virtualenv
                pip # The pip installer
                scipy
                pandas
                csvw
              ]))
            ];
          };
      });
    };
}

Now everything works fine in the nix develop environment, I can import numpy, pandas, scipy, no problem.
HOWEVER, when I tried to use vscode, funny things happened.

I cannot import scipy.
The interpreter I'm using is this:

Also, I noticed that now I could import numpy and pandas from any newly initiated python project following the same procedure described above, but DONOT need to add numpy and pandas in the flake.nix file.
WHY ? !

You probably have pandas and numpy installed globally, which interferes with your understanding of what is Nix making available to you and what it isn't. To make VS Code "see" packages made available in a development shell using nix develop, you need to start VS Code in that shell, ie. something like nix develop; code .. There are ways to make this mode streamlined but, if you are starting from scratch, it's probably easier to go one step at a time.

for some reason, I tried to select a new interpreter in 10 mins, and it now works fine.
I still have no idea why there is an interpreter labelled as Global and why it works...
I created a new project and tried importing lightgbm and starting a conda environment, but it failed again.
I think I will just give up Nix again this time . ...
